# cmake error when installing geant4

Tags: cmake

I/m trying to install Geant4 on my Mac OS. I follow the installation guide of Geant4 (http://geant4-userdoc.web.cern.ch/geant4-userdoc/UsersGuides/InstallationGuide/html/installguide.html). When trying to build with cmake using the command (after creating and moving to my build directory):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install /path/to/source
```

This seems to be executed without any errors but when I try to add additional options, like adding the datasets:

```
cmake -DGEANT4_INSTALL_DATA=ON
```

I do get an error, but it seems it doesn't set the source directory correctly, as if my build directory is seen as my source directory:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/path/to/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

This is weird since /path/to/build is my build directory and I can see the CMakeLists.txt inside my /path/to/source directory.

Comment: When add additional options, do not forget `/path/to/source` argument.

Comment: thanks that works, it didnt mention that in the guide

Comment: But the guide mentions dot as the last parameter: `cmake -DGEANT4_INSTALL_DATA=ON .`

Comment: ah i see, my mistake. thanks again